# receive and Send SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I'd like to create a web service that receives a SOAP in a request and returns another SOAP in response.

I started to develop a WCF with a POST method, but I am confused about what I have exactly to do and what type of parameter I have to choose.
Can anyone help me with a simple code or some thoughts?

Thank you

Below the code I am using for test:

in IService.cs:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "exchange")]
    XmlDocument Exchange(XmlDocument rData);
```

in Service.cs:

```
 public XmlDocument Exchange(XmlDocument rData)
    {
      return rData;
    }
```

Is it possible to exchange SOAP messages using a WSDL web service? if no what I have to change in the code above to do this

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Currently, your question is very vague.

Comment: I added the code @Alexei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I build a web service that support WSE with its special configuration